# How to speed up G++ compilations on ARM architecture (QEMU)

Tags: arm, gitlab, g++, qemu

In one of my docker-based project, I compile [Mod security](https://modsecurity.org/) for an image build for two `BASE_ARCH` with [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/).

- **AMD 64** : works like a charm, the gitlab [CI job](https://gitlab.com/zar3bski/nginx_cerberus/-/jobs/544295422) builds the image in 17 minutes
- **ARM64/V8**: exceed gitlab max duration (1h), the [CI job](https://gitlab.com/zar3bski/nginx_cerberus/-/jobs/544295423) fails (but I am pretty sure it would succeed if it had more time)

Here is the `docker_arm` job

```yaml
docker_arm:
  stage: build
  image: docker:19.03.1
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script: 
    - echo $CI_JOB_TOKEN | docker login -u gitlab-ci-token --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
    - apk update
    - apk add -q qemu
    - echo 'Building $CI_PROJECT_NAME'
  script: 
    - docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
    - docker build --build-arg BASE_ARCH=arm64v8 -t $CI_PROJECT_NAME:arm64v8-latest ./src
    - docker tag $CI_PROJECT_NAME:arm64v8-latest $CI_REGISTRY/zar3bski/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:arm64v8-latest
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/zar3bski/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:arm64v8-latest
```

I wondered if I could tweak either **G++** or **qemu** to speed things up so this job could pass. I am aware of the fact that, because QEMU emulate an ARM64/V8 architecture, I will never get a native performance. All I am looking for is for the job to succeed (even if it needs 40 minutes). In your opinion, which of the following options is the more likely to provide a stable pipeline:

- QEMU optimization
- G++ optimization
- using an other, ARM base `docker:19.03.1` for building the image (is it only possible in Gitlab?)

### Edit

It does not seem possible to run `image: arm64v8/docker:19.03.1` on Gitlab shared runners

Comment: Using native cross-compiler sounds like the most promising option.

Comment: The details escape me now so this may not be very helpful. I used an OBS (Open build System) that did this kind of thing before docker came along and you could inject native binaries into you emulated world to get native speed. The native binaries in this case would have to be a cross-cimpiler built to run on AMD64 that targets ARMv8.

Comment: Here's a link that might lead you somewhere https://www.mail-archive.com/meego-dev@meego.com/msg07639.html This may not be possible with docker, but I don't know for sure.